# Crashing of Android project due to carouselView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working for a PCL project where I have the `carouselView` in my design page. When I run this on iOS, it is working perfectly, but when running on Android, it is getting crashed. Can someone help me to this out?

Comment: Are you using XF carouselview? it's bugged. Try https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

Comment: Yeah I am using carouselView,i tried the link provided by you ,it is displaying the whitepage.

Comment: Hi All, I have tried with your given link but I am getting white page when I go to that page. I don't understand what the cause. Can please suggest any thing is missing.

Comment: Xamarin carousel view works well. If you need help to sort things out please provide xaml and code behind.

Comment: add a repo on GitHub

Comment: make sure you install it on ALL platforms

Comment: It's working on Android for me. What's the error?